# Adding Style to Customer Dropdown

Tags: magento2, customer, css

how to add the styling for the dropdown? in the tutorial they just say "the last touch is adding styles". But i can't find the correct styles in the luma directory and don't know what to change

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-practice.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styling for the dropdown is in

> vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less

under **.customer-welcome**. This goes into the custom theme under the

> web/css/source/_extend.less